# Pulling data from collection using Iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a small issue. The below code snippet works well if i directly dump it in the body tag

```
      {{#each tasks}}
   <ol> <li>Router Name: {{ routerName }}</li>   
    <li>Router Enable: {{Enable}}</li></ol>
         {{/each}}
```

However, when I wrap it within a template and try call it via a route (iron router), it fails to show the query result.

```
<template name ='ManagementConfig'
      {{#each tasks}}
   <ol> <li>Router Name: {{ routerName }}</li>   
    <li>Router Enable: {{Enable}}</li></ol>
         {{/each}}
</template>
```

Route.js:

```
Router.route('/ManagementConfig',{ name:'ManagementConfig' });
```

Everything apart from the above works well within the template and the route. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **ManagementConfig** template don't have access to tasks object. You can fix this by creating a helper method and passing the data.

```
Template. ManagementConfig.helpers({
    'tasks': function(){
        //Change this to your task data
        return Lists.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked. So my take is that each time you want to query or display something off the db via a route, I need to define a separate helper class, correct?

Comment: @blueren yes you should use helper function to pass data but there are also other ways to pass data. You should look at meteor docs. Helper function can be used not just for passing data but can also be used for filtering something. Helper are something you going to be using on regular basis while working on meteor application so get a clear understanding on it.